# custom partition in kafka using .net (using hash based algorithm )

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to use  custom partition in kafka using .net application.I have created a topic , which is divided in 15 partition. I have multiple message , that comes to our web services.  I want to use partition in a way that each message goes to its partition when comes to our service. each message has unique identifier and always comes with that identifier. So suppose the message came for 2345 id and first time it is stored in partition 1 , then always this message should go on this partition.

In java i found some code that was using hash based algorithm to rotate the message in the partition. can we implement these functionality in .net?.
I found some thing in  librdkafka, but this feature in under development.  I have to implement custom partitioner in kafka using .net.

Please help me or give me some suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: I want to decide the message will go on which partition.I have to write some algorithm for it like has based algorithm using .net.I have to distribute the message among 15 partition , if i  I have more than 500 id of message . I want that  kafka producer to smart  enough to distribute the message in partition. like partitioner, and each message will go on its partition assigned. If new message id come then kafka producer should decide the partition.  Can u suggest me some example using .net. how can we  decide that key ? using .net

Answer (score 2):

If I properly understand your usecase you want a message with a particular identifier to be stored on a particular partition.

Kafka is smart enough to handle this, you must use the identifier as the Key of the message , Kafka  will determine the partition using that Key which I presume will not be changing for a particular message type. Kafka will always store the message with same Key on a particular partition.

Comment: Thanks sammy , k ,i want to decide the message will go on which partition.I have to write some algorithm for it like has based algorithm using .net.I have to distribute the message among 15 partition , if i  I have more than 500 id of message . I want that  kafka producer to smart  enough to distribute the message in partition. like partitioner, and each message will go on its partition assigned. If new message id come then kafka producer should decide the partition.  Can u suggest me some example using .net. how can we  decide that key ? using .net

Comment: You may need to google it for .net especially. But just a warning if you follow this approach then its' quite presumable that you would be using the no of partitions in your algorithm as well. ( something like messageid % no of partitions) In case you further increased the partitions then you may end up with a jargon.